# How do you make code reusable?

Tags: code-reuse

Any code can be reused in a way or an other, at least if you modify the code. Random code is not very reusable as such. When I read some books, they usually say that you should explicitly make the code reusable by taking into account other situations of code usage too. But certain code should not be an omnipotent all doing class either.

I would like to have reusable code that I don't have to change later. How do you make code reusable? What are the requirements for code being reusable? What are the things that reusable code should definitely have and what things are optional?

Comment: A word of warning: "reusable code that I don't have to change later" isn't necessarily something you wish to strive for. Changing your code is not inherently negative. Embracing refactoring can sometimes be very productive. So why exactly do you want to make your code reusable?

Comment: Sure all code can be made better in the future, if you are up to it. But when I make reusable code, I expect that I can just take it into use later without needing to worry about things.

Comment: Down the YAGNI rabbit hole we go... do you really need to water-down the original intent to make it ultra-generic or are you better off sticking to the task at hand? Frameworks are reusable, applications not so much. This question is 7 years old so I assume the OP has worked it out by now, this is for fellow Googlers to ponder. Just an observation.

Comment: Assume someone else will use your classes for various purposes

Answer (score 64, accepted):

See [10 tips on writing reusable code](http://hoskinator.blogspot.com/2006/06/10-tips-on-writing-reusable-code.html) for some help.

1. Keep the code DRY. Dry means "Don't Repeat Yourself".
2. Make a class/method do just one thing.
3. Write unit tests for your classes AND make it easy to test classes.
4. Remove the business logic or main code away from any framework code
5. Try to think more abstractly and use Interfaces and Abstract classes.
6. Code for extension. Write code that can easily be extended in the future.
7. Don't write code that isn't needed.
8. Try to reduce coupling.
9. Be more Modular
10. Write code like your code is an External API

Comment: This concentrates on tactics. But tactics without a good strategy is just motion without progress. First you need to create a solid plan for reuse, and then sell that plan to senior management.

Comment: #2 is great. "Do one thing, and do it well". If functions/methods are really self-contained, then you can just copy them into other projects as needed. #6 is harder to understand, and I think is probably something that could be expanded to fill a whole book (and probably has)...

Comment: For the series "Last but not least". For personal experience I use to develop as much as I can following the 10th rule. In MVC application, my controllers returns only a JSON. Proper view will call that service and build the webpage. In this way I can export my application for a mobile app, for example, or standalone client and so on.

Comment: All the tips are great.  I think #10 in particular is the golden rule.

Comment: I thought this might help too: http://noobieprogrammer.blogspot.com/2020/06/coding-tips-how-to-fix-bugs-easier-and.html

Answer (score 15):

If you take the Test-Driven Development approach, then your code only becomes re-usable as your refactor based on forthcoming scenarios.

Personally I find constantly refactoring produces cleaner code than trying to second-guess what scenarios I need to code a particular class for.

Comment: You say "constantly" but I find that a little vague as that would mean infinitely working on the same code base. Can you give me a more concrete metric? You write a function/method, you write a unit test for it, that causes a refactor, and then on average how many iterations beyond that? How do you know when you're done or can at least move on?

Answer (score 12):

More than anything else, maintainability makes code reusable.

Reusability is rarely a worthwhile goal in itself. Rather, it is a by-product of writing code that is well structured, easily maintainable and useful.

If you set out to make reusable code, you often find yourself trying to take into account requirements for behaviour that might be required in future projects. No matter how good you become at this, you'll find that you get these future-proofing requirements wrong.

On the other hand, if you start with the bare requirements of the current project, you will find that your code can be clean and tight and elegant. When you're working on another project that needs similar functionality, you will naturally adapt your original code.

I suggest looking at the best-practices for your chosen programming language / paradigm (eg. Patterns and SOLID for Java / C# types), the Lean / Agile programming literature, and (of course) the book "Code Complete". Understanding the advantages and disadvantages of these approaches will improve your coding practice no end. All your code will then become reausable - but 'by accident', rather than by design.

Also, see here: [Writing Maintainable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162805/writing-maintainable-code)

Answer (score 7):

You'll write various modules (parts) when writing a relatively big project. Reusable code in practice means you'll have create libraries that other projects needing that same functionality can use.

So, you have to identify modules that can be reused, for that

1. Identify the core competence of each module. For instance, if your project has to compress files, you'll have a module that will handle file compression. Do **NOT** make it do more than **ONE THING**. One thing only.
2. Write a library (or class) that will handle file compression, without needing anything more than the file to be compressed, the output and the compression format. This will decouple the module from the rest of the project, enabling it to be (re)used in a different setting.
3. You don't have to get it perfect the first time, when you actually reuse the library you will probably find out flaws in the design (for instance, you didn't make it modular enough to be able to add new compression formats easily) and you can fix them the second time around and improve the reusability of your module. The more you reuse it (and fix the flaws), the easier it'll become to reuse.

The most important thing to consider is decoupling, if you write tightly coupled code reusability is the first casualty.

Leave all the needed state or context outside the library. Add methods to specify the state to the library.

Comment: I like the idea of library. It is then clear, when the reusable code is in the library.

Answer (score 7):

For most definitions of "reuse", reuse of code is a myth, at least in my experience. Can you tell I have some scars from this? :-)

By reuse, I don't mean taking existing source files and beating them into submission until a new component or service falls out. I mean taking a specific component or service and reusing it without alteration.

I think the first step is to get yourself into a mindset that it's going to take at least 3 iterations to create a reusable component. Why 3? Because the first time you try to reuse a component, you always discover something that it can't handle. So then you have to change it. This happens a couple of times, until finally you have a component that at least appears to be reusable.

The other approach is to do an expensive forward-looking design. But then the cost is all up-front, and the benefits (may) appear some time down the road. If your boss insists that the current project schedule always dominates, then this approach won't work.

Answer (score 6):

Object-orientation allows you to refactor code into superclasses.  This is perhaps the easiest, cheapest and most effective kind of reuse. Ordinary class inheritance doesn't require a lot of thinking about "other situations"; you don't have to build "omnipotent" code.

Beyond simple inheritance, reuse is something you find more than you invent.  You find reuse situations when you want to reuse one of your own packages to solve a slightly different problem.  When you want to reuse a package that doesn't precisely fit the new situation, you have two choices.

1. Copy it and fix it.  You now have to nearly similar packages -- a costly mistake.
2. Make the original package reusable in two situations.

Just do that for reuse.  Nothing more.  Too much thinking about "potential" reuse and undefined "other situations" can become a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Others have mentioned these tactics, but here they are formally. These three will get you very far:

- Adhere to the [Single Responsibility
  Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - it ensures your class only "does one thing", which means it's more likely it will be reusable for another application which includes that same thing.
- Adhere to the [Liskov
  Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - it ensures your code "does what it's supposed without surprises", which means it's more likely it will be reusable for another application that needs the same thing done.
- Adhere to the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) - it ensures your code can be made to behave differently without modifying its source, which means it's more likely to be reusable without direct modification.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above mentioned items, I'd say:

- Make those functions generic which you need to reuse
- Use configuration files and make the code use the properties defined in files/db
- Clearly factor your code into such functions/classes that those provide independent functionality and can be used in different scenarios and define those scenarios using the config files

Answer (score 1):

I would add the concept of "Class composition over class inheritance" (which is derived from other answers here). 
That way the "composed" object doesn't care about the internal structure of the object it depends on - only its behavior, which leads to better encapsulation and easier maintainability (testing, less details to care about). 
In languages such as C# and Java it is often crucial since there is no multiple inheritance so it helps avoiding inheritance graph hell u might have.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, modular code is more reusable than non-modular code.

One way to help towards modular code is to use encapsulation, see encapsulation theory here:
http://www.edmundkirwan.com/

Ed.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid reinventing the wheel. That's it. And that by itself has many benefits mentioned above. If you do need to change something, then you just create another piece of code, another class, another constant, library, etc... it helps you and the rest of the developers working in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Comment, **in detail**, everything that seems like it might be confusing when you come back to the code next time. Excessively verbose comments can be slightly annoying, but they're far better than sparse comments, and can save hours of trying to figure out WTF you were doing last time.