# How to write a reusable code in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, code-reuse

Can any one provide me some tips to write reusable code in PHP / CakePHP?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268258/how-do-you-make-code-reusable

Comment: but can u give me some tips in cakePHP........the code which should be maintained easily

Comment: @deceze can u give me an example how to write a method in AppController which can be used by more than one Controllers

Comment: Here you go: `function foo() { return true; }` You can use this virtually anywhere with no side effects! Seriously though, this is impossible to answer without a concrete situation. The tips in the linked question help you to generally write more reusable code. It's the best answer you can get for this question.

Comment: @deceze : consider this situation : i have 3 tables named 1.brands,2.categories,3.catalog.these three tables are independent(no relations) all have each controller and model. i need to write a function to delete a record from these tables i don't want to write delete function in all the 3 controllers instead of that i need to write a single function in AppController.how will write the code for this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [how to] write a single [delete] function in AppController

Okay, I'll bite. You'd code it almost exactly as you would code it in the individual controllers, you just need to replace the parts that **vary** with **variables**.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Session');

    function delete($id) {
        $model = $this->modelClass;  // holds the primary model name
        if (!$this->$model->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Couldn't delete $model record $id.");
        }
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Read through Cake's source code to learn what variables are there for you to use. Read through more source code, especially of Components and Behaviors, which by definition are reusable, to learn more specific techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think anyone mentioned components... this is really where the re-usable stuff should go in CakePHP, at least in my opinion, as I see it, the controller is unique, as is the model, and the component is where you put re-usable code to be called by the controllers.

It really depends on what you're trying to do, if you are just re-using code within a class (where it doesn't have any real utility outside of that class), then don't bother with a component, just use a function in the class.. however, when you find yourself using a function that is approximately the same in more than one controller, then put it into a class..

IMO the best thing is to just always try to break your classes into logical functions as you create them and then only worry about creating a component later on, out of a function in the class, meaning that if you aren't sure if you are going to re-use something, don't spend the extra time making it a component at first as that can easily be done later (but just takes a bit more work / thinking it through)...

if you know ahead of time you are going to be reusing a function then just go ahead and put it into a component to begin with.

(another thing in Cakephp that is great is that within the folders for model, controller, component... you can make your own folders and put files into them without cakephp caring where they are, as long as they are in the overall correct directory (i.e. controller, if its a controller) so, if you have a bunch of controllers that, say are for doing an action that you think of as "updating user profile information" then you just create a folder for this and put all those in there and you can do the same for components that relate to this (within the component directory)... but when you call a controller in this folder, you don't have to reference the folder in the calling url.. something I find very handy as it saves a lot of tedious work while allowing you to keep your class files very organized)

Comment: I agree with Rick, I use custom components all the time to store any code that i plan on reusing. Also I didn't know about the sub folder trick, this might come in handy, thanks

Comment: i started this discussion to know how to resuse the code with in a project but you guyz are leading me to reuse the code over many projects. thanks alot and waiting for more tips

Answer (score 2):

Create method in your app_controller.php and use it in other controllers.

```
// app/app_controller.php
public function _foo($params){
    // do something
}

// app/controllers/some_controller.php
public function foo($params){
    $this->_foo($params);
    // do something else
}

// app/controllers/other_controller.php
public function foo($params){
    $this->_foo($params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about the almighty plugin. I realize that this goes slightly against the comments in the main question. But the ultimate form of code reusability in cakephp is a plugin.